# Conditionally adding a button to a custom UITableViewCell - Button appears in wrong cell on scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I'm programmatically creating a `UIButton` and adding to the view of an IBOutlet `UIButton` in an XIB for a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Upon a check for "displayCustomButtonOfType", the button's instance is added to the cell's customButtonView.

Within the cell's class, the customButtonView is being set to nil within the `prepareForReuse` method.

What is happening on scroll is that the cell's custom button appears in other cells and upon scrolling back, the custom button appears in a different cell.

All text that appears in the cells is appearing as expected.

Is there an approved manner to add and remove a programmatically created `UIButton` to a custom `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Don't just set `customButtonView` to `nil` in `prepareForReuse`. Also remove the button from its `superview`.

Comment: Thanks Maddy.  This nasty behaviour will disappear and reappear if you do not do this.  I set the tag of the button to 1 and delete the button from within the the prepareForReuse of the custom cell class like so:  `[(UIButton *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:1]  removeFromSuperview];`.  You're a lifesaver, man.  I'll have to buy one of your apps in thanks for the insight.